# Need help designing an enzyme immunoassay (EIA)

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, microbiology, immunology, elisa

I have a FITC-labelled DNA sequence and an anti-FITC antibody, however this antibody is not conjugated with HRP or any other enzyme. I work in a lab with limited finances, so is there a way I could make use of these without having to order an HRP conjugated antibody to be used in a detection assay?

Comment: Could you make this a fluorescent assay and simply detect the FITC itself? Do you have a fluorescent plate reader? Or won't the FITC be at high enough levels to detect on its own, and you need the signal amplification of primary and secondary antibodies?

Comment: Thanks Matt! I have already done this, i.e. use a fluorescent plate reader to detect the FITC labelled DNA Seq. However, I was trying to find a way to design an ELISA assay without needing a conjugated antibody. But thanks for your suggestion, i'll keep searching!